# Why f is a first integral?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

**Definitions**

Let $X$ be a vector field of $C^1$ class defined on a open set $A \subset R^n$.  $f$ is a *first integral* if:

a) $ f $ is constant all along orbit of $X$;

b) $ f $ is not a constant in any open subset of $A$.

**Problem**

Let $f: A \to R$ be $C^1$ class such that $D f(p) \dot X(p) = 0$ and $Df(p) \neq 0$ for all $p \in A$.  Prove that $ f $ is a first integral of $X$

**My attempt**

$$
D f(p) X(p) = 0\\
X(p) = 0
$$

Then $p$ is a singular point of $X$, therefore $p$ is a solution of $x' = X(x)$, as $p$ is a point, $f(p)$ is equal to a constant for all $p \in A$.

Is this correct?

For the item *b* of the definition, I don't have any idea how to show this.

Comment: If $ Df(p) \neq 0 $ then clearly it $ f $ cannot be constant on any neighborhood of $ p $, *immediately* from the definition of derivative.  Literally write out the definition of the derivative and there's little else to do.

Comment: thanks, my friend! I Got it!!